# Probability of three disjoint events

Tags: probability

I have a question which I haven't been able to figure out.

> Given three disjoint events $X,Y,$ and $Z$ find
>
> a) the probability that exactly one event occurs
>
> b) the probability that exactly two of the events occur.

So far, the progress I have made on a) is $$P(\text{exactly one}) = [P(X)(1 - P(Y))(1 - P(Z))] + [P(Y)(1 - P(X))(1 - P(Z))] + [P(Z)(1 - P(X))(1 - P(Y))].$$

I took a similar approach for the second one, too. However, given that these sets are disjoint, I think that I might be headed in the wrong direction.

Comment: If by disjoint you mean mutually exclusive then knowing that, say, $X$ occurs already tells you that $Y,Z$ do not occur.  So the answer to part $a$ is $P(X)+P(Y)+P(Z)$ and the answer to part $b$ is $0$.  Otherwise, what did you mean by "disjoint"?

Comment: Indeed, the definition of *disjoint* is the key to this question.  Disjoint events have no common outcomes; they are mutually exclusive; the cannot occur simultaneously; *et cetera*.

Answer (score 5):

(a) The probability you are interested in is given by:
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}(A\cap B^{c}\cap C^{c}) + \mathbb{P}(A^{c}\cap B\cap C^{c}) + \mathbb{P}(A^{c}\cap B^{c}\cap C)
\end{align*}

Since $A\cap B = \varnothing$, we conclude that $A\subseteq B^{c}$.

Moreover, since $A\cap C = \varnothing$, we conclude that $A\subseteq C^{c}$.

Therefore $A\subseteq B^{c}\cap C^{c}$, whence we get that $A\cap B^{c}\cap C^{c} = A$.

Similarly, $A^{c}\cap B\cap C^{c} = B$ and $A^{c}\cap B^{c}\cap C = C$, and we are done.

(b) As @lulu has mentioned, such probability equals zero because $A$, $B$ and $C$ are pairwise disjoint.

More precisely, one has
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}(A\cap B\cap C^{c}) + \mathbb{P}(A\cap B^{c}\cap C) + \mathbb{P}(A^{c}\cap B\cap C) = 3\times \mathbb{P}(\varnothing) = 0
\end{align*}

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: We have not been provided that the events are *exhaustive*, merely that they are *mutually exclusive* (aka *disjoint*).

Comment: @GrahamKemp Thanks for pointing that out. I have fixed my argument. I think it is ok this time.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. For the sake of simplicity -> what would be the difference if the events are mutually exclusive?

Comment: Maybe I have not understood your question, but we have assumed they are mutually exclusive in order to solve the problem.

Comment: I had worded my last comment incorrectly, so let me rephrase: For the sake of curiosity(and understanding), how would it change given that these events are mutually exclusive?

Comment: If I got it right, the fact that they are mutually exclusive implies that

$$\mathbb{P}(A\cap B^{c}\cap C^{c}) = \mathbb{P}(A)$$

Similar results apply to the other two cases. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: @askdokTheBest Disjoint universally implies mutually exclusive; [the converse holds when the sample space is finite](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4333280/21813). $\quad$ There are [conflicting definitions](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4632982/21813) on whether mutual exclusivity (correspondingly: disjointedness) is defined collectionwise or pairwise. This answer, which I agree with, uses the latter definition.  $\quad$ If it is given only that the events are mutually exclusive, then this answer can be tweaked to give the same results, as suggested by user0102's comment above this.